# SAS Equivalent to R Vector-to-Matrix

Tags: r, sas

I've been trying to do something that's very easy to do in R in SAS. Basically, I have a table with *2n* columns and one row. I would like to have a table with *n* columns and two rows.

This is basically what I'm trying to do, in R:

```
x <- c(1:10)

y <- matrix(x, nrow = 2, ncol = 5, byrow = T)
```

Which takes us from:

```
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

to:

```
> y

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

So in SAS, let's say I have the following example dataset:

```
data test;
    input v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 e_v1 e_v2 e_v3 e_v4 e_v5;
    datalines;
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
;
run;
```

I am trying to make it such that e_v1 is actually row two of v1, etc. - in other words, I want to go from this one-row dataset (x in the R example above) to a two-row dataset (y in the R example above). Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you!

Comment: You may need to check the `shape` from `IML`

Comment: `shape` from `IML` worked! Thank you.

Comment: In the future please specify if you're using Base SAS or IML :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution for your example.

```
data tworow;
   set test(keep=v:) test(keep=e: rename=(e_v1-e_v5=v1-v5));
   run;
```

Comment: This should have been obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need `proc transpose` for this (in base SAS). Firstly create another column say `rowNum` using `ceil()` or `floor()`:

```
data foo;
set test;
rowNum = floor(_N_,5);
run;
```

After this you can use proc transpose in your desired form.

Answer (score 1):

For those without SAS IML but with access to PROC FCMP:

```sas
/* This data is just for my example, see question for WORK.TEST */
DATA test2;
    Array x [16];
    Do i = 1 to 16;
        x[i] = i;
    End;
    Drop i;
Run;

PROC FCMP;
    /*
    SAS equivalent of R's matrix(x, nrow) function. To get the effect of R's
    "byrow" argument, use PROC TRANSPOSE.

    Arguments
        indata:  Character value naming the input data set
        outdata: Character value naming the output data set
        nrow:    Desired number of rows in the output
    */
    Subroutine row_to_table(indata $, outdata $, nrow);
        Array in_values [1, 1] / nosymbols;
        Array out_values [1, 1] / nosymbols;

        rc = read_array(indata, in_values);

        in_length = dim1(in_values) * dim2(in_values);
        ncol = ceilz(in_length / nrow);
        Call dynamic_array(out_values, nrow, ncol);

        out_row = 1;
        out_col = 1;
        Do in_row = 1 to dim1(in_values);
            Do in_col = 1 to dim2(in_values) while (out_row <= dim1(out_values));
                out_values[out_row, out_col] = in_values[in_row, in_col];
                If out_col = dim2(out_values) then do;
                    out_row = out_row + 1;
                    out_col = 1;
                End;
                Else out_col = out_col + 1;
            End;
        End;

        rc = write_array(outdata, out_values);
    Endsub;

    /* Original example */
    Call row_to_table('test', 'result1', 2);
    /* 16 items to 3 rows: should add missing values as filler */
    Call row_to_table('test2', 'result2', 3);
Run;
```

result1:

```
Obs    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5

1      1     2     3     4     5
2      6     7     8     9    10
```

result2:

```
Obs    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6

1      1     2     3     4     5     6
2      7     8     9    10    11    12
3     13    14    15    16     .     .
```

This isn't a perfect recreation, since R recycles a vector to fill in "extra" matrix elements, but that's a very R-specific behavior.